# How do I determine if a 3D-point is inside a solid object using SQL in PostGIS?

Tags: 3d, postgis, intersection

I have some troubles to determine if a 3D-point is inside a solid object or not, using PostGIS.

I've tried creating the most simple of solids:

```
ST_MakeSolid('POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (
    ((0 0 0, 0 1 0, 1 1 0, 1 0 0, 0 0 0)),
    ((0 0 0, 0 1 0, 0 1 1, 0 0 1, 0 0 0)),
    ((0 0 0, 1 0 0, 1 0 1, 0 0 1, 0 0 0)),
    ((1 1 1, 1 0 1, 0 0 1, 0 1 1, 1 1 1)),
    ((1 1 1, 1 0 1, 1 0 0, 1 1 0, 1 1 1)),
    ((1 1 1, 1 1 0, 0 1 0, 0 1 1, 1 1 1))
  )'::geometry)
```

and want to know if following 3D-point `'POINT Z (0.5 0.5 0.5)'::geometry` is inside of it.

```
SELECT ST_3DIntersects(
  ST_MakeSolid('POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (
    ((0 0 0, 0 1 0, 1 1 0, 1 0 0, 0 0 0)),
    ((0 0 0, 0 1 0, 0 1 1, 0 0 1, 0 0 0)),
    ((0 0 0, 1 0 0, 1 0 1, 0 0 1, 0 0 0)),
    ((1 1 1, 1 0 1, 0 0 1, 0 1 1, 1 1 1)),
    ((1 1 1, 1 0 1, 1 0 0, 1 1 0, 1 1 1)),
    ((1 1 1, 1 1 0, 0 1 0, 0 1 1, 1 1 1))
  )'::geometry),
  ST_MakeSolid('POINT Z (0.5 0.5 0.5)'::geometry)
);
```

The code above returns false. I suspect that ST_3DIntersects only returns true if the point intersects with the surface of my solid. This I suspect because this query returns true:

```
SELECT ST_3DIntersects(
  ST_MakeSolid('POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (
    ((0 0 0, 0 1 0, 1 1 0, 1 0 0, 0 0 0)),
    ((0 0 0, 0 1 0, 0 1 1, 0 0 1, 0 0 0)),
    ((0 0 0, 1 0 0, 1 0 1, 0 0 1, 0 0 0)),
    ((1 1 1, 1 0 1, 0 0 1, 0 1 1, 1 1 1)),
    ((1 1 1, 1 0 1, 1 0 0, 1 1 0, 1 1 1)),
    ((1 1 1, 1 1 0, 0 1 0, 0 1 1, 1 1 1))
  )'::geometry),
  ST_MakeSolid('POINT Z (1 1 1)'::geometry)
);
```

I know that i could use the `&&&`-function but my solid will be more complex and that is why I can't use the bounding box of my solids.

Do anyone know which 3D-function to use to determine if points is inside solid objects?